# Does Chrome have an error console like the one in Firefox?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

In Firefox if there is a JavaScript error or anything like that it shows up in the Error Console. I have a problem on my site that only seems to happen in Chrome, and I think it's a JavaScript error. I can't find anything remotely related to an error console like in Firefox. So how the heck do I debug it? (Yes, I am new to web development.)

EDIT: I don't think I worded this correctly. I do know about the dev tools in Chrome, but they aren't showing me anything at all, at least that I can see. The console shows no error or warnings, only a blank box.

EDIT again: Found it wasn't a javascript error like I thought, but a problem with a plugin I was using on the site. That would explain why I was getting nothing in the console.

Comment: Just use the internet...

Comment: -1 This is like asking if calculators have a sqrt button on a math forum. You gotta do some research first.

Comment: May be you should delete this question as it litters search results.. This will bring you the Peer Pressure badge if you don't have one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes....

It has a console....

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> **or** <kbd>F12</kbd>

But seriously....

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has dev tools built in - press F12. Javascript errors will show as a small red cross in the bottom right and you can use the console / sources tabs to debug.